# Where is the option to flag a question off-topic and it doesn't qualify for any suggested site?

Tags: support, flags, migration

I recently encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461135/what-s-the-name-of-this-menu-bar) and it doesn't seem relevant for SO (maybe I'm wrong!) or any of the suggested options that flagging "this is off-topic..." suggests (SuperUser, SSCCE, SO checklist, Server Fault, recommendation), or suggesting another site (meta, superuser, tex, dba, sharepoint).

Regardless of the qualifications of the question I cited earlier, where's the option on the  "suggest it moves to another site" list to choose either a StackExchange site from a drop-down, or (preferably) just click a radio button for "let moderation figure it out, but it doesn't go here!"?

Comment: If there are so many potential duplicates, MAYBE THERE IS ACTUALLY PROBLEM.

Comment: If that were true, wouldn't all the duplicates of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) indicate a much bigger problem?